# How to position images in HTML5?

Tags: html, image, position

I don't like when the images stay to the left.

I have tried to do this:

```
<img src="logo.jpeg" position="100,100>
```

That didn't work. Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: HTML is not a layout language. Learn CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use margin property for positioning.
But in my opinion it is better to use css, just learn basic of html and all other things are easy to done in css.